# pymysql connection: read_timeout has no effect

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, timeout, pymysql

When creating a connection to a MySQL database via sqlalchemy and [`pymysql`](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/connections.html) connector, I want to set a timeout for queries that take too long:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
eng = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://username:password@host:port/database",
    connect_args={'connect_timeout': 1.0, 'read_timeout': 1.0})
```

With this code I expect any query to raise an exception latest after 2 seconds (1 for the connection itself, 1 for the reading operation). However a complex SELECT query can run for minutes anyway.

What could be the reasons that the `read_timeout` connection parameter is effectively ignored?